# How can I get my keydown event to work?

Tags: javascript

I have a class `Jugador` that creates a new SVG rect and put it on canvas (pong game) and I want to assign ArrowUp and ArrowDown for the first player, and the key "W" and "A" for the second player for move the "stick".

```
class Jugador {
    constructor(num, coorx, coory, color) {
        this.parent = document.getElementById("svg");
        this.rectan = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        this.parent.appendChild(this.rectan);
        this.jugador = document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[num];
        this.jugador.setAttribute("x", coorx);
        this.jugador.setAttribute("y", coory);
        this.jugador.setAttribute("rx", "14");
        this.jugador.setAttribute("ry", "14");
        this.jugador.setAttribute("width", "35");
        this.jugador.setAttribute("height", "250");
        this.jugador.setAttribute("onkeydown", "movimiento(event)");
        this.jugador.style.fill = color;
        this.jugador.style.stroke = "black";
        this.jugador.style.strokeWidth = "2";
    }

    movimiento(event) {
        let code = event.keyCode || event.which;

        if (document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0]) {
            if (code == 38) { // flecha arriba
                pala1.setAttribute("y", (pala1.getAttribute("y") + 5));
            } else if (code == 40) { //flecha abajo
                pala1.setAttribute("y", (pala1.getAttribute("y") - 5));
            }
        }
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("rect")[1]) {
            if (code == 113) { // letra Q
                pala2.setAttribute("y", (pala2.getAttribute("y") + 5));
            } else if (code == 97) { //letra A
                pala2.setAttribute("y", (pala2.getAttribute("y") - 5));
            }
        }
    }
}

var pala1 = new Jugador(0, 50, 300, "orange");
var pala2 = new Jugador(1, 1715, 300, "blue");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
this.jugador.setAttribute("onkeydown", "movimiento(event)");
```

you could do

```
this.jugador.addEventListener("onkeydown", movimiento);
```

but still, the event will be fired only if you have the focus on that element.

instead you can bind the events on the whole document:

```
document.body.addEventListener("onkeydown", movimiento);
```